# Automapper IDataReader to List<T> - Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper, datareader, idatareader

As the title suggests I am trying to map a DataReader object to a List of Objects, here is the code I am using, I have tried this using both AutoMapper 4.2.1 and 3.3.1

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                 cfg.CreateMap<IDataReader, MemberChangesDto>()                
                .ForMember(dest => dest.MemberNo, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => (string)src["Member_No"]))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.OrganisationName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => (string)src["Member_Name"]))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.MemberJoinDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => (string)src["Membership_StartDate"]))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ResignationDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => (string)src["Membership_Resigned_Date"]))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.MemberStatusId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => (string)src["Membership_Status_Code"]));
            }
            );
```

Once the automapper is initialized I verify it by using

```
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

This returns no errors, then I call the mapping

```
IDataReader dataTableReader = memberChangesDS.Tables[2].CreateDataReader();
IList<MemberChangesDto> members = Mapper.Map<IList<MemberChangesDto>>(dataTableReader);
```

However this returns the error

> {"Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>   Mapping types:
>   IDataReader -> IList`1
>   System.Data.IDataReader -> System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[MemberChangesDto, Models,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]
>   Destination path:
>   IList`1
>   Source value: System.Data.DataTableReader"}

The Object I am trying to map to looks like this.

```
public class MemberChangesDto
{
    public string MemberNo { get; set; }
    public string OrganisationName { get; set; }
    public string MemberJoinDate { get; set; }
    public string ResignationDate { get; set; }
    public string MemberStatusId { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction, I have used AutoMapper from object to object with no problem, however I think the IDataReader is causing the problem here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This method create instances of objects from SQL query not using AutoMapper:

```
   public IEnumerable<T> FillDataRows<T>(String query, params SqlParameter[] sqlParams) {
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().ToList();
        IList<T> result = new List<T>();

        var source = FillDataRows(query, sqlParams).ToList();
        var firstInSource = source.FirstOrDefault();
        if (firstInSource == null)
            return result;

        //remove properties not exist in source
        properties.RemoveAll(p => firstInSource.Table.Columns.Contains(p.Name) == false);

        foreach (var row in source) {
            var item = createItemFromRow<T>((DataRow)row, properties);
            result.Add(item);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private T createItemFromRow<T>(DataRow row, IList<PropertyInfo> properties) {
        T item = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        foreach (var property in properties) {
            if (row[property.Name] != System.DBNull.Value)
                property.SetValue(item, row[property.Name], null);
        }
        return item;
    } 

    public void FillDataSet(DataSet ds, String dataTable, String query, params SqlParameter[] sqlParams) {
        using (var cn = new SqlConnection(this.connectionString)) {
            cn.Open();
            using (var cmd = cn.CreateCommand()) {
                cmd.CommandTimeout = commandTimeout;
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                if (sqlParams != null && sqlParams.Length > 0)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParams);
                using (var adapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd)) {
                    adapter.Fill(ds, dataTable);
                }
            }
            cn.Close();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<DataRow> FillDataRows(String query, params SqlParameter[] sqlParams) {
        var ds = new DataSet();
        FillDataSet(ds, "Result", query, sqlParams);
        return ds.Tables["Result"].Rows.OfType<DataRow>();
    }
```

Sample:

```
var sql = "select MemberNo = Member_No, OrganisationName = Member_Name ... From MYTABLES where Member_No = @ID"; 
var results = FillDataRows<MemberChangesDto>(sql, new SqlParameter("@ID", 12345));
```